# Cant update dll reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a dll Domain project. Then I use this dll as reference in a `ASP.NET WebForms` project.
I added a property in the Domain project and I cannot get it on the ASP.NET project.

Steps I have tried:

1. Clean and rebuild the Domain project.
2. Remove the reference from the ASP.NET and add manually again.
3. Clean and rebuild the ASP.NET project.

It is the first time I am getting this error, and I cannot figure out why. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on the property, do you see the option to add the property to the solution?  If so, you should be able to add the property from there.  If not, what options do you see when you right click on the property?